# How to prevent spammers to send me blank emails from my contact form

Tags: javascript, php, email, contact-form, spam-prevention

I have simple contact form on my website and few days ago I started to receive half blank emails from contact form on website.

They looking the same as the sample below, filled out just Name and email field, but Phone and Message fields are empty:

**Name:**   5906f36c9c72b
**E-mail:** njhjlee@gmail.com (any time different emails)
**Phone:**
**Message:**

This is HTML code:

```
<form id="contactform" action="assets/php/mail_submit.php" method="post">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required/>
                            </div><!--column-->
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email" required/>
                            </div><!--column-->
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                                <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон" required/>
                            </div><!--column-->
                            <p class="antispam">Leave this empty: <input type="text" name="url" /></p>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                                <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" id="message" required></textarea>
                            </div><!--column-->
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                                <input class="btn btn-default" id="submit" type="submit" value="Send"/>
                            </div><!--column-->

                        </div><!--row-->
                    </form>
```

This is PHP script:

```
<?php

if (!isset($_REQUEST['name']) || !isset($_REQUEST['email']) || 
!isset($_REQUEST['message']) || !isset($_REQUEST['phone'])) {
die();
}

if (isset($_POST['name']) || isset($_POST['email']) || 
isset($_POST['message']) || isset($_POST['phone']) && !empty($_POST['name']) 
|| !empty($_POST['email']) || !empty($_POST['message']) | 
!empty($_POST['phone'])) {

$your_email="my@mail.com";



$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$message=$_POST['message'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];

$to      = $your_email;
$subject = "My Website: New Message! \r\n";


$message = '
        <html>
        <head>
          <title>Message from '. $name .'</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <table class="table">
            <tr>
              <th align="right">Name:</th>
              <td align="left">'. $name .'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th align="right">E-mail:</th>
              <td align="left">'. $email .'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th align="right">Phone:</th>
              <td align="left">'. $phone .'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th align="right">Message:</th>
              <td align="left">'. $message .'</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </body>
        </html>';

        $headers .= "From: no-reply@website.com\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n";
        $headers .= "Return-Path: $email\r\n";
        $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP \r\n";   
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";

   mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

} else {
die();
}
?>
```

This is AJAX script:

```
function IsEmail(email) {
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]
{2,4})+$/;
    return regex.test(email);
}

if($("#contactform").length!=0){
    $("#contactform").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = $("#name").val(),
        email = $("#email").val(),
        phone = $("#phone").val(),
        message = $("#message").val(),
        dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email+ '&phone=' + phone + 
'&message=' + message;

        if (name === '' || !IsEmail(email) || phone === '' || message === 
'') {
            $('#valid-issue').html('Not correct data').slideDown();
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/assets/php/mail_submit.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function () {
                    $('#contactform').slideUp();
                    $('#valid-issue').html('Thank you. Message was sent successfully.').show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I've checked logs and found that all spammer bots was from Thor network and with different IPs. I tried captcha but it doesn't help. Help with advise please...

Comment: Use a captcha, that prevents most bots. If it doesn't help, you didn't implement it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinforce your javascript checking, also use "trim":

```
  var name = $("#name").val().trim();
```

Use  PHP str_word_count to reinforce the checking for empty message.

eg.

```
$message= filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'message');

// check $message is not empty and that it contains more than 5 words
if($message != "" || str_word_count($message) < 5) {
     echo "Message is valid"

}else{
     echo "Invalid Message";
}
```

I few  other wrong things with your PHP code:
You should never access superglobal POST/GET variables directly. Use PHP inbuilt filter functions or a customised one.

```
$name= filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
```

Or you can use

```
function FilterData($value){

    $trimmed = trim($value);
    $notags = strip_tags($trimmed);
    return $notags;
}
```

Then:

```
$name = FilterData($_POST['name']);
```

For the email you can  use

```
$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
```

More info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Hi, I've tried it but spam emails still coming. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Are the messages still empty?